# String or binary data would be truncated IN SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ZAIN
(
  ZID INT NOT NULL,
  CID VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  NAME NVARCHAR(50)NULL,
  HIREDATE DATE NULL
)
```

When I execute the following `INSERT` statement I get an error:

```
INSERT INTO ZAIN 
VALUES('12', 'ASD', 'HOHOO', 'JAN-10-1999')
```

The error is:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to insert a three-character string into a two-character `varchar` column. What do _you_ think the solution might be?

Comment: sorry my mistake but the error is different

Comment: Do you actually bother to read these error messages before you post them?

Comment: are you going to tell me solution or not ?

Comment: @XyedXainHaider - please leave the tags as-is. This is not a SQL Management Studio problem. It is SQL server telling you that you can't stuff a 3 character string `ASD` into a two character wide field (`CID`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issue with your insert statement

1. The column `ZID` is INT and you are passing 12 as string like '12' you can remove `'` but it won't give an error.
2. The column `CID` is Varchar(2) and you are trying to insert 3 character string `'ASD'` it will give a data truncation error. **ie your error here**
3. But if you fix the above error another one will pop-up like `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`. It is with the Date format you are giving for HIREDATE column `'JAN-10-1999'`. SQL can take date format in MM/dd/yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd etc. the format you specified cannot be converted automatically to date format by SQL. So try 01/10/1999 or 1999-01-10..else try something with CONVERT() function

[MSD DOC for CONVERT function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: THANKYOU FOR HELPING ME I FOUND THE ANSWER

INSERT INTO ZAIN VALUES('12','ASD','HOHOO','2013-12-05')

DATE SHOULD LIKE THIS :)